# Is there a way to check what percentage of your close votes are on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Let's say I have cast 100 close votes.

How can I easily determine how many of those close votes are on questions which are currently closed? This would be useful for understanding how well my personal close voting preference matches a site's overall philosophy on when questions should be closed, reopened, etc.

Even more awesome would be:

1. Close votes on questions which were closed (even if reopened)
2. Close votes on questions which are currently closed
3. Close votes on questions which are deleted

Comment: If you go to the "votes" tab in your profile and filter on close votes, it will say \[closed\] or \[migrated\] next to the titles of the questions you've voted on. This works OK for checking on your most recent votes, but when you have 724 close votes cast it's a bit much to count them manually :)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't easily do that unless you use hammer's suggestion of manually going through your Votes tab in your profile. You can get a rough idea by comparing your # of close votes in your profile with the # of closed questions with your name on it using [this SE data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/90447), however deleted posts are not included in Data.SE, so it won't be exact. Also, Data.SE is only available to graduated sites, so if you're trying to look for data on a beta site, that query won't work.

Comment: @hammar right, I wasn't so excited to open and view that many questions, especially since some are deleted... which get closed first, too

Comment: Two relevant points; the first is mentioned by Rachel, whatever you do deleted posts will be excluded. The second is that on the larger sites you're not matching a sites overall philosophy but a _tags_; an important distinction...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I would be interested in that sort of information too (breakdown by tag, etc) but I will first be happy with just seeing the information to begin with :-)